# Convert erb ruby code to slim template

Tags: ruby, erb, slim-lang

Below is an erb ruby code which is want to convert in slim template

```
    <div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= review.rating%> ></div>
```

In above template i am confused as there are two equals to sign

online converter is giving something like this

```
.star-rating data-score="<haml_loud"  review.rating &gt;
```

But its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
.star-rating data-score=review.rating
```

Since you're (apparently) using Slim, not Haml, you don't need `haml_loud` at all.

Answer (score 1):

`<%= ... >` in Erb means to evaluate the expression inside, and include the result in the outer context. Thus if the rating would be 99, then `data-score=99` would become part of the html. That is fine.

The generated output seems wrong. The trailing `&gt;` should be inside a string, just as the opening counterpart `"<haml_loud`. And as jeffdill2 correctly pointed out, there is no need to use `haml_loud`. Just use:

```
.star-rating data-score=review.rating
```